# Series and Parallel Circuit

Tags: parallel, series

In the following schematic, if

- R1 = 42ohm,
- R3 = 33ohm,
- VT = 220V, and
- IR2 = 1A

How do I find R2?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJNeQG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Algebra.  Let 'I1' be the current through R2.  Ohms law.  parallel resistances 1/RP=1/R1+1/R2 etc.  Now do your homework:)

Comment: I do not understand by Let"I1" be the current through R2

Comment: Asking us to solve what *looks* like a homework problem is off-topic for this site as it doesn't help anyone: you or us.  If you have a specific question about some aspect of the problem, then please update your question. Otherwise I expect this question will likely be closed soon.

Comment: This is not a homework problem, I took it from a electronic book which i unable to solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\$ I_{R2} = 1 \text{ amp}\$,  \$ R1 = 47 \Omega \$, \$ R3 = 33 \Omega \$, \$VT = 220 \text{ volt} \$

Now since R1 and R2 are in parallel

$$ 
I_{R1} \cdot R1 = I_{R2} \cdot R2
$$

Solve to find \$I_{R1}\$ then substitute in

$$
I_{R2} \cdot R2 + \left( I_{R1} + I_{R2} \right) \cdot R_3 = VT
$$

The rest is basic arithmetic.  If your having problems post what you have tried but you won't learn if one of us does it for you.

Comment: u mean IR1 = (1*R2)/47 but idk r2

Comment: When you put that into the second equation you have only R2 unknown and should be able to calculate it from there.